# Laravel 5.2 MongoDB & MySQL in Same App Error

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel

I have a MongoDB connection & MySQL Connection details setup in my `config/database.php` file. I can connect to the MongoDB Details and get a response but when i try connect to the MySQL database, i get the following error:

```
FatalThrowableError in Builder.php line 1514:
Call to a member function compileSelect() on null
```

I've tried the solutions from this page: 
[Issue with Out of the box Laravel Authentication](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/861) but none of the solutions have worked.

I'm not using any authentication on the app, just querying a MySQL database to return data.

[Updated]

Route link from `app/Http/routes.php`

```
Route::get('v1/{showdata}/{name}', 'ShowDataController@percentData');
```

Controller: `ShowDataController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\ShowData;
use App\MongoDataPull;

class ShowDataController extends BaseController
{

public function percentData($showdata, $name)
{
    $showdata;
    $name;

        $signupsremaining = 0;
        //Percentage Calculator
        if ((ShowData::where('name', '=', $name)->first()) === null) {
        // If not found, change status to Not Listed
        $percentagetakeup = 'Not Listed';
    } else {
        // If found, Run Percentage Calculator
        $totalrequired = ShowData::select('total_required')->where('name', '=', $name)->value('total_required');
        $currentinterest = ShowData::select('current_interest')->where('name', '=', $name)->value('current_interest');
        $percentagetakeup = round((($currentinterest) / $totalrequired) * 100);

        // Calcualte the number of signups remaining for the fibrehood.
        $signupsremaining = $totalrequired - ($currentinterest);

        if ($signupsremaining < 0) {
            $signupsremaining = 0;
        } else {
            $signupsremaining = $signupsremaining;
        }
    }

    return ['percentagetakeup' => $percentagetakeup, 'signupsremaining' => $signupsremaining];

}

}
```

From ShowData Model `ShowData.php`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShowData extends Model
{
    protected $table='qualify';
    protected $fillable=[
        'id',
        'name',
        'total_required',
        'current_interest',
        'status'
    ];

}
```

Comment: can you please share your MySQL query code?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Updated Code. Is there anymore info you need?

Comment: [Update] I commented out the MongoDB connection details and left MySQL details and the MySQL query worked. If i comment out the MySQL connection details, the MongoDB Query works. I just can't have both working at the same time. (Edit wouldn't let me type)